# oracle 12c with two database instances

Tags: oracle12c

I search a lot in google before creating this post , but couldn't solve my issue.

I installed oracle server 12c with single instance on a windows machine , and everything was working normally.

Now , I want to import a schema that contain some arabic characters (character set AR8ISO8859P6).
I tried to create a new pluggable database with this character set but I couldn't find how to set the character set for a PDB.
So I went to plan B , which is creating a new database (which is I think a new database instance and container) , where I could change the default character set , and which contain a pluggable database.
the database was installed successfully , but the issue is that I couldn't connect to it from SQLPlus or any other client tool.

when I checked the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files, I didn't find any entry related to the newly created database.I tried to add it there but without success.
when I try to connect using :

```
sqlplus sys/password@new_orcl as sysdba
```

I'm getting :

> ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

How can I connect to this new container database and its pluggable database?

Comment: You can check [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-pdb-character-sets-12cr2) article on setting up different character set at each PDB level. Also, please note this is supported from Oracle 12.2 version.

Comment: @learningloop the article also suggest to create a new CDB. the issue is that I'm not able to connect to the new CDB where I'm getting ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred